# Why are we getting cURL error 56, SSL errorno 104?

Tags: ssl, curl, payment-gateway, tls1.2

I am working on an online store that uses a custom PHP script to interface with Orbital Chase Paymentech as a gateway.  Recently, the store's website has been failing to process orders because CURL is encountering an error.  In particular, `curl_errno()` returns `56` and `curl_error()` returns `SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104`.

The payment request to Paymentech, however, is going through just fine.  (Ie, our request is formatted correctly, and credit cards are being charged.)  The correct IPs *are* whitelisted at Paymentech's end.

Here is our CURL configuration:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Chase Paymentech Gateway/1.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have tried just about every sensible permutation of CURL settings above to no avail.  We always get CURL error 56 with SSL read errno 104.  I've tried the suggestions from other stackoverflow questions, also to no avail.

I've pasted a sample log below from one payment request (with some sensitive info obscured).  As you can see, the request is running over `TLSv1.2 / AES128-GCM-SHA256`.  I have verified with Chase that this is an acceptable SSL version and cipher.

The certificate on the site is up to date, from Geotrust / RapidSSL, and a fresh one has been installed since I started working on this issue.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?  As best I can tell, there's something about our CURL / SSL Certificate setup that is causing the communication to fail, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the cause is or how to fix it.  Please help!

**CURL Output:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*   Trying 206.253.186.176..., referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
* Connected to orbital1.chasepaymentech.com (206.253.186.176) port 443 (#0), referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
* successfully set certificate verify locations:, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
  CApath: none, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES128-GCM-SHA256, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
* Server certificate:, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*      subject: C=US; ST=New York; L=New York; O=Chase Paymentech Solutions, LLC; OU=CPS ENA; CN=orbital1.chasepaymentech.com, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*      start date: 2017-01-17 00:00:00 GMT, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*      expire date: 2018-01-18 23:59:59 GMT, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*      subjectAltName: orbital1.chasepaymentech.com matched, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*      issuer: C=US; O=Symantec Corporation; OU=Symantec Trust Network; CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
*      SSL certificate verify ok., referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
> POST /AUTHORIZE HTTP/1.0\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
MIME-Version: 1.0\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Content-type: application/PTI41\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Content-length: 1148\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Content-transfer-encoding: text\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Request-number: 1\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Document-type: Request\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Merchant-id: ############\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Host: orbital1.chasepaymentech.com\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
            <Request>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                <NewOrder>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <IndustryType>EC</IndustryType>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <MessageType>AC</MessageType>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <BIN>000002</BIN>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <MerchantID>############</MerchantID>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <TerminalID>001</TerminalID>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AccountNum>################</AccountNum>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <Exp>0118</Exp>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <CurrencyCode123CurrencyCode>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <CurrencyExponent>2</CurrencyExponent>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <CardSecValInd>1</CardSecValInd>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <CardSecVal>###</CardSecVal>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSzip>A0B1C2</AVSzip>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSaddress1>123 Something St</AVSaddress1>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVScity>Somewhere</AVScity>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSstate>ON</AVSstate>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSphoneNum></AVSphoneNum>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSname>Testing</AVSname>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVScountryCode>CA</AVScountryCode>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDestzip>A0B1C2</AVSDestzip>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDestaddress1>123 Something St</AVSDestaddress1>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDestcity>Somewhere</AVSDestcity>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDeststate>ON</AVSDeststate>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDestphoneNum></AVSDestphoneNum>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDestname>Testing</AVSDestname>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <AVSDestcountryCode>CA</AVSDestcountryCode>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <OrderID>1343</OrderID>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                    <Amount>1450</Amount>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
                </NewOrder>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
            </Request>\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
         /authorize HTTP/1.1\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Host: orbital1.chasepaymentech.com\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
Accept: */*\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
\r, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
* SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
* Closing connection 0, referer: https://www.==our-url===.org/index.php/payment
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently restarting the firewall on our server fixed the issue.  We turned it off to do some testing with our certificate issuer, and we noticed that the website worked.  When we turned the firewall back on it was still working.